# What does "GC Pause" in go executor trace mean?

Tags: go, garbage-collection, trace

I use go trace to track the execution time of the function.

Although there are many objects created in the program, is the gc pause time too long?

According to the source code, "GC pasue" uses the GCTime field, which corresponds to the GCDone event, while GCSTW and GCSweep are separate events. It looks like GcTime is the total GC time, not STW (pasue) time.

**What exactly does the "GC Pause" column mean? Will the user goroutine be paused during this time?**

[cmd/trace/goroutines.go#L298](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/go1.21.0/src/cmd/trace/goroutines.go#L298)

```html
<table class="details">
<tr>
<th onclick="reloadTable('sortby', 'SweepTime')" class="sweep-time"> GC sweeping</th>
<th onclick="reloadTable('sortby', 'GCTime')" class="pause-time"> GC pause</th>
</tr>
{{range .GList}}
  <tr>
    <td> {{prettyDuration .SweepTime}} {{percent .SweepTime .TotalTime}}</td>
    <td> {{prettyDuration .GCTime}} {{percent .GCTime .TotalTime}}</td>
  </tr>
{{end}}
</table>
```

[internal/trace/goroutines.go#L275](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/go1.21.0/src/internal/trace/goroutines.go#L275)

```golang
const (
    EvGCStart           = 7  // GC start [timestamp, seq, stack id]
    EvGCDone            = 8  // GC done [timestamp]
    EvSTWStart          = 9  // GC mark termination start [timestamp, kind]
    EvSTWDone           = 10 // GC mark termination done [timestamp]
    EvGCSweepStart      = 11 // GC sweep start [timestamp, stack id]
    EvGCSweepDone       = 12 // GC sweep done [timestamp, swept, reclaimed]
)

func GoroutineStats() {
    // ...

    case EvGCStart:
        gcStartTime = ev.Ts
    case EvGCDone:
        for _, g := range gs {
            if g.EndTime != 0 {
                continue
            }
            if gcStartTime < g.CreationTime {
                g.GCTime += ev.Ts - g.CreationTime
            } else {
                g.GCTime += ev.Ts - gcStartTime
            }
        }
        gcStartTime = 0 // indicates gc is inactive.
}
```

This is the code for the test, a simplified version of the real program.

https://go.dev/play/p/idO-4ycK41K

gernerate trace and open trace web:

```
$ go version
go version go1.21.0 darwin/amd64

$ go test -bench=BenchmarkGoTrace -benchtime=1000x -run=NONE -trace=trace.out
cpu: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1038NG7 CPU @ 2.00GHz
BenchmarkGoTrace-8          1000      22500692 ns/op


$ go tool trace trace.out
```

Below are some screenshots of the go trace tool page:

[image: trace web]

[image: region]

[image: gc pause]

Comment: Confirmed as a go bug: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/62443